# How to get Console log on develop tools (F12) on IE using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, console.log

I'm Using IE11 and need to get console log message. I am using Java selenium for that.

Comment: that's not for IE browser. I need to access with IE

Comment: It is better you show us what did you tried till now will help us to understand the issue in better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use code like below.

```
LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get("browser");
```

Reference:

[Java Code Examples for org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries)